# What does struct node *head=NULL initialisation mean?

Tags: linked-list

I am new to linked list .
while creating the linked list initially we write struct node *head=NULL;
WHAT DOES IT MEAN ?

Comment: What do **you** think it means?

Answer (score 4):

Initially it contains some *garbage value*
. SO,  in order to Create a linked List (Single) you need to initialize it to  *NULL*. And thus it becomes easier to create the First node *( by checking the condition head==NULL)* which is true so the first node is created. Now you we can  add newnodes to the existing Linked List just by traversing till end and adding a newnode.
So, if you have not Initialized the head pointer to *NULL*, You cannot create a Linked List.

```
if(head==NULL)
    {
    newnode->next=NULL;             
    head=newnode; 
    }
    else
    {
        ptr=head;
        while(ptr->next!=NULL)
        {
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next=newnode;
        newnode->next=NULL;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For beginners, initialisers are hard to read. Best is IMHO to read them as the combination of a declaration and an assignment:

```
struct node *p = NULL;
```

is equivalent to:

```
struct node *p;
p = NULL;
```

Note that the initialiser is applied to the pointer (p *is* a pointer) not to where it points at. (it points *nowhere*, since it is NULL)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are creating a linked list, we have to initialize it and since it doesn't have any nodes in the start (empty linked list in the beginning), the start/head points to null. That's what is meant by *head=NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Zero is an invalid address. A pointer variable equal to null with address null means that the pointer variable variable does not point to a valid memory location.